# C Program to Find the Sum of Series 1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4 + … + n^4

Tags: c, sum

I'm done with sum of Series `1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + … + n^`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
 {
    int number, i;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the maximum values of series n: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum = pow(((number * (number + 1) ) / 2),2);
    printf("Sum of the series : ");
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (i != number)
            printf("%d^3 + ", i);
        else
            printf("%d^3 = %d ", i, sum);
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

But I'm not getting with 4th power. Any help with 4th power?

sample input is 2 and sample output is 17

mathematically 1^4 + 2^4= 17  (for 4th power)

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exactly are you trying to do? Sample input and expected output?

Comment: I suppose that the assignment was to let the program "brutally" calculate the result summing each term, not to find a closed formula for the result.

Comment: sample input is 2 and sample output is 17

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the 17 as output after running your program myself.

Comment: no no .. i'm talking about 4th power my sample input is 2 and sample output is 17... mathematically 1^4 + 2^4= 17

Answer (score 4):

As discussed, use brute force. Be aware of the maximum value limit of `int` type, use `unsigned long long` if necessary.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int number, i;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter the maximum values of series n: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("Sum of the series : ");
    for (i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
    {
        sum += pow(i,4);

        if (i < number)
        {
            printf("%d^4 + ", i);
        }
        else
            printf("%d^4 = %d ", i, sum);            
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This version gives you flexibility to deal with both cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int numTerms, power, i;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter number of terms in the series n: ");
    scanf("%d", &numTerms);
    printf("\nEnter power of the series n: ");
    scanf("%d", &power);
    printf("\nSum of the series: ");
    for (i = 1; i <= numTerms; ++i)
    {
        sum += pow(i, power);

        if (i < numTerms)
        {
            printf("%d^%d + ", i, power);
        }
        else
            printf("%d^%d = %d \n", i, power, sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The formula for `1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4 + ... + n^4` is `(6n^5 + 15n^4 + 10n^3 - n) / 30`.

Translated to C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>

int fn(int n, int power)
{
    double f = 0.0;
    int i;

    if (n < 0) 
        f = -fn(-n, power); /* negatives */
    else switch (power) {
        case 0:
            f = 1.0;
            break;
        case 1:
            f = (pow(n, 2) + n) / 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            f = (2 * pow(n, 3) + 3 * pow(n, 2) + n) / 6;
            break;
        case 3:
            f = (pow(n, 4) + 2 * pow(n, 3) + 3 * pow(n, 2)) / 4;
            break;
        case 4:
            f = (6 * pow(n, 5) + 15 * pow(n, 4) + 10 * pow(n, 3) - n) / 30;
            break;
        case 5:
            f = (2 * pow(n, 6) + 6 * pow(n, 5) + 5 * pow(n, 4) - pow(n, 2)) / 12;
            break;
        default:
            if (power < 0) break;
            /*
                fn(28,6) overflows INT_MAX
                This means 28 iterations in the worst case, use brute force:
            */
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                f += pow(i, power);
                if (f > INT_MAX) break;
            }
    }
    if (f < INT_MIN || f > INT_MAX) return 0;
    return (int)f;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n, power, result;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter power:  ");
    scanf("%d", &power);
    if ((result = fn(n, power)) == 0 && n != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error computing fn(%d,%d)\n", n, power);
    } else {    
        printf("Sum of series: %d\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More info: [Computing sum of series ^1 ... ^10](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)

[image]

Comment: As pointed out, I feel that using the analytical identity/formula for the series sum is a poorer way of doing it as you want to write code that is modular and reusable. The approach in your original question (and this answer) does not work for general power n, and would need infinite switch/case statements to extend to all n. The only advantage yielded here is that the computation time is O(1).

Comment: Suggest: (considering your interest is formulas) `((((6*n + 15)*n + 10)*n + 0)*n - 1)*n/30.0`  This form is more accurate and faster.

Comment: @elleciel, your suggested code (using brute force as a reusable solution) is a pain for `1000^2`

Comment: @Alter Mann: That's untrue. It takes my CPU 18 milliseconds to handle 100000^2 via brute force. It grows O(n). I see you have defaulted to brute force, which is the right approach.

Comment: Your CPU is not relevant, executing `pow` 10000 times is expensive on old machines, and I have defaulted (but as pointed out you can follow the table) in the case of `power>5` because `28^6` overflows `INT_MAX`, 28 iterations in the worst case!

Comment: @AlterMann You're plucking these from thin air. You just claimed sum to 1000^2 is expensive but my point is that even sum to 100000^2 is cheap. What old machines are you referring to? I have a Pre-Nehalem processor and a pre-2007 router (<500 MHz single core) and both will execute `pow` 100,000 times still easily under 1 second.

Comment: @Alter Mann Invoking higher order analytic formulae is poor programming practice in this case. It only makes sense if the formula is guaranteed to converge on the solution in the entire domain of the argument passed through (e.g. Runge–Kutta methods), otherwise the code is not reusable. As I've pointed out, you can solve the integer overflow using an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: The description of your results (under 1 second) is too vague, but this is not the issue, consider the bottleneck of calling `fn(>1000,2)` on each line of a big `data.csv` using your approach. Maybe it's ugly, but my code is reusable as it is embedded in a single function, performance in the worst case (answer is edited in order to catch overflow) is guaranteed to be O(1)...O(28), this is better than O(n). Excuse my poor english.